# Jquery-JQGrid-ASP.NET MVC-3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

Does anyone has idea how to capture the selected rowid in jqgrid and pass it to other controller?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [onSelectRow(rowid,status)](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) event handler wich will be always called if the row will be selected or unselected. So you will have the `rowid` of the row which you need and can call any other controller using the `rowid` as a parameter.

Comment: @Hari Gillala: I don't know what you don't know. :-) All will be more clear if you include some code where you use jqGrid in your question. Then I could try gives you some advices.